# Shiny selectInput to select all from dropdown

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have `selectInput` dropdown like this:

```
selectInput("locInput", "Location", choices=c("All","New Mexico", "Colorado", "California"))
```

What I want to achieve is to make selectInput by default not filter by anything, as in when "All" is selected then it should list all observations (so from California, Colorado etc.)
So what I tried to do is create simple logic for this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered<-reactive({
    shows %>%
    filter(Length >= input$lenInput[1],
           Length <= input$lenInput[2],
           if (input$locInput != "All"){
           Location==input$locInput
    })
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas what can I change in order to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

There wonderful `shinyWidgets` package which already has the `Select All` feature in its `pickerInput`

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- basicPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    pickerInput("locInput","Location", choices=c("New Mexico", "Colorado", "California"), options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = T)
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({
    print(input$locInput)
  })

}

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you use OBS to record the video and speed it up?

Comment: @its.me.adam No, I use LICEcap screen recorder, which is easy to use. https://licecap.en.softonic.com/

Answer (score 6):

You need an else condition. Surprisingly, this works if the condition is `TRUE`, but if it is `FALSE`, then `filter` has an error since you have an empty condition. To solve this, just add `else TRUE`, which will filter no rows (since `TRUE` is `TRUE` for all rows):

```
data(iris)
iris %>% filter(Petal.Length > 6.4,
                if (FALSE) Sepal.Length > 7.7 else TRUE)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
2          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
3          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
4          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica

iris %>% filter(Petal.Length > 6.4,
                if (TRUE) Sepal.Length > 7.6 else TRUE)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
2          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica
3          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0 virginica
```