# How do you filter a data frame in a shiny document and display a datatable?

Tags: shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to filter a data frame and then do some simple ggplots off of the data. I've tried to leverage the R studio example on Shiny documents along with the following SO post on the subject:

[Reactively filtering/subsetting a data frame in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840334/reactively-filtering-subsetting-a-data-frame-in-shiny)

Here is my code.

````
---
title: "Shiny Filter Test"
author: "Novice"
date: "12/13/2019"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

```


```{r}

library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_break", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 10)
)

cdat <- reactive({

data <- tibble(x = c(10,20,35), y = c("a","b","c"))

  data %>% 
  filter(x %in% input$n_break)

output$table <- DT::renderDT({
        cdat()
    }, options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
})
```
````

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?  When I run the code I get my dropdown box, but that is all. No errors. Just no filtered datatable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The closing brackets of your reactive are at the wrong place. They should close once you have filtered the data.

````
---
title: "Shiny Filter Test"
author: "Novice"
date: "12/13/2019"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE
)
```

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_break", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 10)
)

cdat <- reactive({
    data <- tibble(x = c(10,20,35), y = c("a","b","c"))  
    data %>% filter(x %in% input$n_break)
})

DT::renderDT({
  cdat()
}, options = list(scrollX = is ))

```
````

A remark on the `reactive`: if you plan to extend this futher, such that the filtered data is used elsewhere, it makes sense to do the filtering in a `reactive` function. However, if this is not the case I would just do the filtering inside the `renderDT`:

````
---
title: "Shiny Filter Test"
author: "Novice"
date: "12/13/2019"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE
)
```


```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

data <- tibble(x = c(10,20,35), y = c("a","b","c"))

inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_break", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 10)
)

DT::renderDT({
  data %>% filter(x %in% input$n_break)
}, options = list(scrollX = TRUE))

```
````