# How to return all values instead of none when selectInput is blank

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In my reprex below I am attempting to filter the mtcars data set using two `selectInput` objects. These work as expected when one or more values are selected by the user. However, the default behaviour is for each `selectInput` to initialise with no value selected and this is interpreted to mean no rows are returned in the `DTOutput` table.

How do I change this behaviour so that "none selected" in the `selectInput` object translates to "return all" for that feature in the data frame?

The key thing here is that any solution should scale well: think hundreds of unique values over several features. Ideally the user should filter by **exception**: any filter without an input should return all its options; any filter with one or more user-defined values should only return these in the data frame.

My attempt at doing this is annotated below but does not work. I have also tried `filters$cyl <- ifelse(is.null(input$cyl), ...` but this did not work either.

```
## A simple test of filtering a data frame
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
library(shinythemes)
library(tidyverse)
rm(list = ls())

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("cyl", "cylinders", choices = unique(mtcars$cyl),
                  selected = "", # I tried with and without these selected arguments.
                  selectize = T, multiple = T),
      selectInput("gear", "gears", choices = unique(mtcars$gear),
                  selected = "",
                  selectize = T, multiple = T)
      ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("cars"),
      textOutput("choices")
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  #>>
  # An attempt to handle blank filter values to mean return all values
  filters <- reactiveValues(cyl = NULL,
                            gear = NULL)
  update <- reactive({
    paste(input$cyl, input$gear)
  })

  observeEvent(update(), {
    filters$cyl <- ifelse(input$cyl == "", unique(mtcars$cyl), input$cyl) # I also tried is.null(input$cyl)
    filters$gear  <-  ifelse(input$gear == "", unique(mtcars$gear), input$gear)
  })
  #<<

  #>>
  # Debug text field that *should* show all values when none selected for either selectInput
  output$choices <- renderText(paste(filters$cyl, filters$gear))
  #<<

  #>>
  # Output. This should render the whole table on initialisation but is blank
  output$cars <- renderDT(datatable(mtcars %>%
                                      filter(cyl %in% filters$cyl,
                                             gear %in% filters$gear)))
  #<<
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add in the same values you supply to `choices` to `selected`.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("cyl", "cylinders", choices = unique(mtcars$cyl),
                  selected = unique(mtcars$cyl), # I tried with and without these selected arguments.
                  selectize = T, multiple = T),
      selectInput("gear", "gears", choices = unique(mtcars$gear),
                  selected = unique(mtcars$gear),
                  selectize = T, multiple = T)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("cars"),
      textOutput("choices")
    )
  )
)
```

If you want to have a button for selecting or deselecting all, then please find this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218614/shiny-selectinput-to-select-all-from-dropdown) with the solution using `shinyWidgets`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would be a simple, elegant way forward if I was interested in the mtcars dataset but this is a simplification for a problem involving a data frame with hundreds of options across three filters. It's not feasible to have the user deselect things from a hundred-long list. I would like the default option to be everything, unless the user specifically overrides this for one or more filters.

Comment: Added link above to post answering your question.